# PyCharm States Certain Package Requirements are Not Satisfied Even Though I Installed on a Previous Session

Tags: python, pycharm, requirements.txt

Everytime I open a specific project, PyCharm shows **"Package requirements 'scikit-learn>=0.22.2', 'scipy>=1.4.1', 'statsmodel>=0.11.1' are not satisfied"**, even though I selected "**Install requirements**" in a prior session.

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the PyCharm terminal, it says that these requirements are already satisfied.

[image]

Also, when I import classes/functions from sklearn, e.g., `sklearn.utils.validation`, sklearn is highlighted in red.

How come the virtual environment, which is called "feature-engine", does not recognize these libraries?

Comment: Check the default environment of the project. And every project terminal should have a different virtual environment.

Comment: It seems that PyCharm does not want to accept the download. I've gone to "Preferences" --> "Python Interpreter" and added Scikit-learn, Statsmodels, and Scipy. The packages continue to install. The installation is never completed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this, very annoying, after a while I discovered that I misspelled the package name, I wrote `sphinxcontrib.plantuml` instead of `sphinxcontrib-plantuml`.

It looks like there's an inconsistency in how PyCharm evaluates package names between installing them and checking whether they are installed.